# Windows 8 get list of folder names as string?

Tags: windows-8

I have a folder with a list of folders.  Without manually going through the list and typing the name of each folder, is there a way I can get a new line delimited list of the folders (or file names for that matter) in that directory?

Comment: I tried... searching for an answer to the question and couldn't find one.  I wasn't sure where to start so I assumed this was the environment to ask.

Comment: Side note: I was a bit speechless when [I saw that PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem`  has problems with paths longer than 260 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12697503/935614) while command line's `DIR` has not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, it's pretty simple from the command line:

1. Open a command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then enter "cmd" and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>) (alternatively, just search for "cmd" in windows search)
2. Navigate to the folder in question (e.g. `cd c:\My\Directory`, you can copy this from your explorer window)
3. Use the `dir` command and redirect the output to a file:  `dir > myfile.txt`

That will give you a list of everything in the folder.  [See Here for MS KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196158)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new list of all folders you can use the console. 'CD' into your folder and then use:

```
dir /AD /B /S /O:N > folderlist.txt
```

This displays a list of directories and subdirectories in a given root directory. The output file `folderlist.txt` will be in the parent directory

- `/AD` lists only directories
- `/B` suppresses unnecessary header information
- `/S` searches for sub-directories too
- Sorts the output alphabetically

Full help from `cmd> dir /?`

```
DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
  /C          Display the thousand separator in file sizes.  This is the
              default.  Use /-C to disable display of separator.
  /D          Same as wide but files are list sorted by column.
  /L          Uses lowercase.
  /N          New long list format where filenames are on the far right.
  /O          List by files in sorted order.
  sortorder    N  By name (alphabetic)       S  By size (smallest first)
               E  By extension (alphabetic)  D  By date/time (oldest first)
               G  Group directories first    -  Prefix to reverse order
  /P          Pauses after each screenful of information.
  /Q          Display the owner of the file.
  /R          Display alternate data streams of the file.
  /S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
  /T          Controls which time field displayed or used for sorting
  timefield   C  Creation
              A  Last Access
              W  Last Written
  /W          Uses wide list format.
  /X          This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file
              names.  The format is that of /N with the short name inserted
              before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are
              displayed in its place.
  /4          Displays four-digit years
```

Comment: I appreciate the additional syntax for a recursive list.  Didn't need that in this case but that might come in handy.